# White square showing in GWT app when viewed in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, iframe

After having went through the [GWT StockWatcher tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/index), I find a small UI problem, as shown in this image

[image: Visible white square from hidden iframe]

When I change the background color of body from white to green manually, a small white square becomes visible. I have seen several examples of this, so I'm pretty sure it is not a programming error that I have made. On the contrary, it seems to stem from one of the hidden iframes inserted by GWT, since it disappears when I delete the iframe or all of it's contents.

Also it seems to be a Chrome- or Chrome-GWT-plugin specific issue, since I could not replicate it in Firefox.

Does anyone know the cause/fix of this problem?

Comment: Can you post, what firebug says when you hover over it

Comment: I don't see the artifact in Firefox, so Firebug does not say much :) When I hover over the `iframe` element in Chrome's inspector, it does not seem to correspond to the square - nothing does. However, as mentioned, if I delete the `iframe`, the square disappears.

Comment: I have had the exact same problem since I started using GWT over 2 years ago. I've never found a solution but my problem is exactly as the original poster described. I would also point out that the white box seems to push the whole contents of the page to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I just tried this and it seems to work but its not very well tested.

The body had a margin of 8px on all sides. I set it to 0px with

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
}
```

This seemed to have removed the problem. If you wanted the margin you would have to add it back to a nested element inside your body.

Comment: A bit of a hack but I agree that it should work. Do you know if the problem disappears in production mode (without the hack)?

It puzzles me that there is so little information to be found on this issue, since you run into it so quickly after starting on GWT...

Comment: I am pretty sure I've seen it in production mode (without the hack)